# Copy a Realm from Bundle to Documents, then read it into a local constant, in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift2, realm

Okay, so I’ve got a pre-populated Realm that I built in the bundle of my Swift 2.0 project. I’m trying to copy it to my Documents directory on first launch, then read it from that location and use it from there. It looks like I have the writing to Documents down, but the Realm won’t read into my `let`. Here’s how I’m saving it (this creates the file on disk, so I think all is well):

```
final func copyEmptyDatabaseIfRequired() {
    let documentsPath: AnyObject = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.UserDomainMask,true).first!
    let storePath: String = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("OohRealm.realm")

    if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(storePath) {
        let defaultStorePath : String! = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("OohRealm", ofType: "realm")
        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(defaultStorePath, toPath: storePath)
        } catch _ {
            // Handle nasty goings-on later. No really.
        }
    }
}
```

And here’s how I’m trying to read that file into a local `let` in my Data Manager (this is what isn’t working, I hit the `catch` and my `realm` is `nil`:

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let documentsURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as NSURL
let realmURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("OohRealm.realm")

do {
    realm = try Realm(path: realmURL.absoluteString)
} catch {
    //
}
```

One of the stumbling blocks I’m hitting is that it seems that in Swift 2.0, Apple really want you to interact with the file system using URLs, not Strings, but Realm wants me to give it the `path` as a String. That’s a tricky one.

What might I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this

```
realm = try Realm(path: realmURL.absoluteString)
```

to this

```
realm = try Realm(path: realmURL.path!)
```

`NSUrl`s are meant to represent generic URLs, and can refer to things other than files. The `absoluteString` property may also identify what type of resource this URL is in a prefix. In the case of files it starts with the prefix `file://`. This prefixed string is not appropriate for use with file system libraries like `NSFileManager` or `NSPathUtilities`. Apparently it is not appropriate for `Realm` too.

If you know you're dealing with a file URL, `NSUrl` provides you the `path` property that is the absolute path of your file, and is suitable for file system libraries.

Just as a remark, file system libraries is one of the uses but not the sole purpose of `path`.

Comment: That hasn’t helped, unfortunately. I’m looking at what `path` gives me, and it’s this: `/Users/lukec/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/063AB9C5-3482-4470-BD22-74B5014F5460/data/Containers/Data/Application/B4C176BA-AC7B-467D-B417-74FC03B3CF78/Documents/OohRealm.realm`. Shouldn’t that be a reference just inside the documents directory rather than an absolute URL on disk? Not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Are you sure your realm is being copied successfully? You may be getting `nil` for `defaultStorePath`. Try to log the value of `defaultStorePath` and check whether the destination file exists after copying.

Comment: Oh, and as far as I know `path` is indeed supposed to be the absolute path in case the URL identifies a file.

Comment: @lukech forgot to notify you. Have you solved your problem? I tried your code in my project and it worked well using `path` instead of `absoluteString`. My guess is your realm file is not in the main bundle, so `defaultStorePath` becomes `nil` and the copy throws an exception, which you catch and ignore.

Comment: It was actually being read, turns out I had a race condition and it wasn’t ready in time for the query, so it showed up empty. Thanks for the advice!